# How to apply css changes using IntelliJ with GWT without having to stop/restart program

Tags: css, gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-hosted-mode

When using IntelliJ to write a GWT application and testing in hosted mode is there any way to have a CSS change reflected in the execution of the program without having to stop and restart the application?  Stopping and restarting is such a slow process it makes one want to use java statements instead of css.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Run | Update action (Ctrl+F10).

Answer (score 1):

I generally use firebug for checking the CSS . I launch the application through intelliJ + firefox and using the firebug modify CSS till i get desired results .

Comment: I'll have to investigate this.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in Intellij 13. In the menu choose

```
> Run
> Edit Configuration
> Select "Update resources on frame deactivation"
```